# Uniform convergence of a particular series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'd like to determine the convergence of a series:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^4}{n!}(x^{3n}+x^{-3n})$$

Whether or not this series converges uniformly, or whether it converges at all. Thanks.

Comment: range of $x$? $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, range of x is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: using the ratio test it seems to converge for $x<\infty$ since we end up with $$\dfrac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^4}{n+1}\dfrac{x^{6(n+1)}+1}{x^{6n}+1}\dfrac{1}{x^3}$$

Comment: how do you show uniform convergence?